# Hosting common CSS and JS in a local server

Tags: javascript, css, hosting, shared

The software that I work on has many modules. And these modules all share the same JS and CSS structure. What happens today is all the modules have their own copy of the CSS and JS files. I thought that we could maybe host these files in a spefic module, and all the other applications would consume the files from this new module. Something like cloudflare, but local instead.

Anyone has any tip? What would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: You have to be a little more specific about things. What kind of software? Where is it running?

Apart from that why do the modules have same copies of the same CSS and JS files?

Comment: You could always do it the same way you include external css/js. Note that most browsers (should) dislike external JS due to security, but by the sounds of it you're sitting on a local domain with multiple sites, and could just throw everything you're normally duplicating onto another "site" that lacks a stage 2 auth, and then reference it from your pages.